Swagger-Codegen and openapi-generator Cannot Unmarshall (map) XML Response to Java Object
I tried to use both library "swagger-codegen" and "openapi-generator" however both of them failed to return Response object to DTO object.
I get success response in XML format. But, "ApiClient.java" implementation of the library expect "String.class". This code snippet auto-generated by the library:

The problem is, I expect "Object.class" but it checks "String.class" return type!
Here is the my API definition:


Can I do a configuration to update this auto-generated code block

returnType.equals(String.class)

like this:

returnType.equals(Object.class)

I cannot modify requested API. I need to handle this issue by configuring something in openapi-generator-maven-plugin.
Here is my configurations:

Here is API returnType, it is UserTask object:

I want to handle it as a Java object and it is already generated by openapi library:

Response is success with XML object which is I need.

But unfortunately, since my response is not a String, the code which is generated by OpenApi returns "Content-Type not supported for return type!"

Here is the exceptional step!

In auto-generated code, there is a line for JSON deserialization but there is no a condition to unmarshall XML object:

It just tries to XML response in String type!

Don't use images to post code, post code as text with proper formatting tags. The images are unreadable.

Hello Deinum, I will replace them with text. Thanks for the feedback.
Additionaly, the problem is completly is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78120816/openapi-generated-apiclient-has-no-xml-serializer-deserializer
OpenApi does not provide an XML deserializer. But, there is no answer!
